# The state in class constructor isn't defined when calling function after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't find any info regarding a situation like this, I'm passing **p1** props from my App component to **state** of my Child1 component.

When I call the **buttonHandler** method to see the state of s1 I get this error:

```
Child1.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
```

Class component **"Child1"**

```js
import React from "react";
import { setState } from 'react'

class Child1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.s2 = 0

        this.state = {
           s1: this.props.p1
        }
        console.log(this.state.s1);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // console.log('componentDidMount()')
        console.log('s2 = ' + this.s2);
        this.s2 += 1

        this.setState(() => ({
            s1: this.props.p1 + 1
        }))
    }

    buttonHandler() {
        console.log(this.state.s1);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <h3>State s1</h3>
                    <h4>{this.state.s1}</h4>
                </div>
                <hr />

                <div>
                    <h3>props from p1 to s2</h3>
                    <h4>{this.s2}</h4>
                </div>

                <hr />

                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.buttonHandler}>Push</button>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Child1
```

**App.js**

```js
import './App.css';
import Child1 from './Child1';

function App() {
  return (
    <>

      <Child1 p1={88} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With class instances, you need to [bind the function to the component instance](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance):

```
// Use arrow syntax (recommended) or bind in the constructor
  buttonHandler = () => {
    console.log(this.state.s1);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks Denis, so when i using regular func method it has his own this...

Comment: I didn't see it to much time...thanks again (toda gever)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems with the above code:

1. event listener method binding (in `buttonHandler` method)
2. initializing state with props (in constructor)
3. using prop value inside `setState` (in `componentDidMount`)

For the event listener binding, as seen in Dennis Valsh's answer:

```
buttonHandler = () => {
    console.log(this.state.s1);
};
```

To initialize state with props, its better to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return {s1: props.p1 + 1};
}
```

To update state using props, use the callback argument of `setState`. (See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

```
setState((state,props) =>{
    return {s1: props.p1 + 1};
}
```

However, since what you're trying to do isn't very clear, I'd say you don't need the `componentDidUpdate` at all & the `getDerivedStateFromProps` is sufficient.

Comment: static getDerivedStateFromProps